Installation issues with ubuntu 24.04 and 22.04 on HP Zbook 14 G2
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on HP Zbook 14 G2.
I tried it on all 3 boot options, 1. Legacy = where my boot drive doesn't get detected for some reason (MBR, Secure boot off, USB hard drive->first option), 2. UEFI(with CSM) = here my boot drive is detected with MBR only (for GPT it isn't detected), 3. UEFI(without CSM) = here again my boot drive isn't detected(GPT).
Now, in case 2 I used the interactive installation and used manual partitioning, but whenever I booted, it shows no boot file present. So I tried automated partitioning, but still this issue arises.
Is there some issue with my BIOS or should I just shift to older LTS as I would prefer a easy installation with no issues because I am setting this pc for a family friend and don't want them to run into issues.
Edit: I switched to 22.04 and I was eventually able to boot into the system, but for some reason its not automatic. When it boots, it just starts and shows a line, "reset system" and then continues to boot again, repeatedly. Now if I select to go into boot devices then it stops and there if I select the ssd or the OS boot manager then it doesn't work, but if I select boot from efi file then it shows me options, and BOOTx64.efi does the same thing, repeated booting, but if I select grub.efi, then it works. But, if I restart then still same thing.


Did you check with sha256sum that the download of the iso file was successful (that the sha256sum matches what is stored at the download site)? 2.  What tool/method did you use to create the USB boot drive? 3. How does it work to run Ubuntu live, booted from the USB boot drive? 4. What kind of installation did you create (in the internal drive alongside another operating system (Windows) or in a separate drive)? - Please edit the original question to answer these questions.



No, 2. with rufus and etcher, 3. fine, all apps run fine with no issues, 4. I emptied it, no dual boot, only windows.


Please check the iso file with sha256sum. See this link, or in Windows using Rufus. - You can find the sha256sum at the same website directory as you find the iso file, for example via https://releases.ubuntu.com/

Yep, I checked the SHA256SUM and it matches with the one i got using my file and certutil -hashfile in windows cmd

Okay, got one thing, I switched to 22.04 and I was eventually able to boot into the system, but for some reason its not automatic. When it boots, it just starts and shows a line, "reset system" and then continues to boot again, repeatedly. Now if I select to go into boot devices then it stops and there if I select the ssd or the OS boot manager then it doesn't work, but if I select boot from efi file then it shows me options, and BOOTx64.efi does the same thing, repeated booting, but if I select grub.efi, then it works. If I restart then still same thing, might raise another issue for this.

Just let me know what you think about this.

I'm glad to read about your steps forward :-) Unfortunately I don't recognize your problem, and cannot help you directly. I think your chances for success will increase if you edit your original question and add the content of your comments, or maybe even better, as you suggest, ask a new question (create a new thread) and describe with as much details as possible 'the content of your comments'. -- I have some HP laptops of various age, and I think the newer HPs work best in UEFI mode, with secure boot off (but not booting in CSM). Maybe you can also turn off TPM and/or some other 'locks'.
